Remove pop-up due to preinstalled Tags app, when scanning many NFC tags
My NFC functionality is in place and working. The tags have an empty Message, so I read the ID.
Problem
When there is no data in the message to force open a specific app, a pop-up appears for every NFC tag.
There is no "Always" option in this pop-up to always use my app.
This slows down scanning.
It's not a viable solution to rewrite all the tags.
I've tried

Set the NFC settings to prioritize the current app (my app). This has no effect.
Explored NFC payment app options, but my app is not a payment app, so I can't set a default NFC payment app.
Searched the web for solutions.
Read the official Settings documentation.

Some solutions mention the App Inspector app, which allows me to search for the Tags app and disable it. This does what I want, but I would like the user to be taken to this setting on login to my app.
Expected: A way to select a default NFC app instead of Tags.
Actual: Pop-up every time.
Tentative solution

Check for presence of the Tags app using Package Manager.
Check if it's already disabled.
If present and enabled, take the user to the Disable option for com.android.apps.tags. (Is this the correct package name?)

Edit: On a Samsung phone which had Android 13, the package name was com.android.apps.tag, on a Nexus with Android 8.1.0 and a Zebra with Android 14, it was com.google.android.tag.
Question
I was thinking that it was a simple matter of the correct ACTION constant as for Exact Alarms permission, but since it's for a specific package name, I must do this slightly differently.
How do I solve 1, 2 and 3 in a best practice way? Especially 2.
This code fails silently (nothing in LogCat). Expected: To navigate to the App Info Settings page for the Tabs App. Actual: Nothing happens and no error.
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", "com.android.apps.tags", null));
                startActivity(intent);


Is your question "how do I open the application details screen in Settings for a particular app?" If so, try ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS

It would help if you show your Manifest file and how exactly your Tag is configured (best to use the App "NXP Taginfo" and scan the Tag and save it to an xml file with the save icon and then post the xml here in the question. Because depending on your Tag and Manifest it should be possible (My App does something similar)

Thank you @CommonsWare - that looks like the correct action. I've clarified what I'm asking, and I've debugged a code example that I've appended to the question. For some reason, it doesn't navigate away from my app to that settings page. The same code works for Exact Alarms, but obviously I pass my app's package name for it.

I suspect that com.android.apps.tags is not the package name. Searches on multiple search engines turn up few hits... where this very page is the top one.  To check the package name, you can use an app like this, if the package name is not shown on the Settings details screen for the app.

You might want to look at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/refs/heads/main/src/com/android/nfc/NfcDispatcher.java#560 Depending on various things it does not seem that you can influence any of it's stored preferences. But you probably don't need to if you defined things correctly, but you've not provided the right info in the question to help.

Thanks to your clues I could adb shell cmd package list packages and find the package name. You can also long-press on an app in App Inspector to see it, I found out. I've updated the question, and am looking for answers to step 2 in the potential solution. Cheers!
